# Parallax bug with skrollr

Tags: javascript, css, fixed, parallax, absolute

Here is a jsbin of my code: http://jsbin.com/EKidOyO/1/edit

What I'm trying to achieve (unsuccessfully so far) is that when I you scroll, the red div should stay fixed for a set amount of time then eventually move up and the rest of the page follow.

This works kind of at the moment. However, when you reach the end of the blue `div` that should be the end of the page and not allow you to see white space below the blue div. Also, on smaller viewports you cannot scroll down to see the bottom of the blue `div`.

I cannot work out how to fix this.

Comment: Do the divs need to be `750px` high? It would be much easier if it were percentages.

Comment: Yeah they do. I saw on your example you used percentages. This seems like such a trivial thing to solve but I've spent days on this now. lol

Comment: You need to dynamically calculate the keyframes based on the viewport height, which is currently not supported by skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/69).